# Angular CLI for springboot app in IntelliJ

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-boot, intellij-13

I have a web app for travel and tour. The front end is in Angular JS, HTML 5 for front end and Spring boot, MySQL for backend. The backend server is running. The app loads webpage but on Register form when I enter details. and click Register I get an alrt message of fail.Because the Login.js is tyring to send a POST Request.

Below is the Login.js code. The issue is that on clicking the register button I get the following error on console.
angular.min.js:103 POST http://localhost:63343/registration 404 (Not Found)

```
//Controller for login and signup corresponds to Login.html

travelApp.controller("loginController",["$scope","$http","$location","$cookieStore","$route","baseService",function($scope,$http,$location,$cookieStore,$route,baseService){
    $scope.loginDetails = {email:"",password:""};
    $scope.loginFlag = true;
    $scope.registerDetails = {email:"",password:"",firstName:"",lastName:"",userName:""};
     $scope.pwCheck=function(){
            if($scope.registerDetails.password!=$scope.registerDetails.confirmpassword){
                $scope.registerForm.$invalid=true;
                $scope.pwMatch=true;
            }
        };
    
    
    //Function used to check user credentials
    $scope.login = function(){
        
        var request = {
                method : 'POST',
                url : '/login',
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                },
                data : $scope.loginDetails
            }
        $http(request).then(
                function(response) {
                    
                    $scope.$parent.$$childHead.buttonEnable = false;
                    //$scope.apply();
                    baseService.setUserName(response.data.userName);
                    $cookieStore.put('userId',response.data.id);
                    //$cookieStore.put('Email',response.data.);
                    $location.path("/dashboard");
                    
                },
                function(response){
                    alert("Invalid UserName or Password");
                });
        
    }
    //Function used to register
    $scope.register = function(){
        
        $scope.registerDetails.userName = $scope.registerDetails.firstName+" "+ $scope.registerDetails.lastName;
        var request = {
                method : 'POST',
                url : '/registration',
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                },
                data : $scope.registerDetails
            }
        $http(request).then(
                function(response) {
                    $route.reload();
                    alert("Registration is successful");
                    $location.path("/login");
                    $route.reload();
                    
                },
                function(response){
                    alert("fails");
                });
    }
    
}]);
```

I just have a zip file which I loaded in IntelliJ and  IntelliJ was smart enough to install dependencies but the AngularJS framework isnt working properly from angular.min.js because it gives error on POST request from /registration

Comment: Could you please tell the error you get on angular side?

Comment: Basically My Spring boot app is sending post request but cant find path /registeration.  and gives error POST request to the server's /registration endpoint  not found
POST http://localhost:63343/registration 404 (Not Found)

@ RestController
public class UserController {

 UserService userService;
 
 
@ RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public User register(@ Validated(Create.class) @ RequestBody User user) {
  //user.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(user.getPassword()));  
  return userService.createUser(user);
 }
}